# Encoding URL using `encodeURIComponent` does not work with form action

Tags: javascript, html

I just noticed this behavior of `encodeURI` using with `form`. I encoded a url using `encodeURI`.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form">
</form>
<button id="button">Click Me to submit form</button>
</body>
<script>
    var button = document.getElementById("button");
    button.onclick = function() {
        var form = document.getElementById("form");
        var url = "b.html?name=" + encodeURIComponent("First Name");
        form.action = url;
        form.method = "post";
        form.submit();
    }
</script>
</html>
```

On submitting the form I am not getting what I expected in the browser address bar. I was expecting

```
b.html?name=First%20Name
```

What I got is -

```
b.html?name=First Name
```

Can someone please tell me why this is happening?

**Note-**

I am facing this issue only in firefox(I am using version 24.0). On chrome it behaves as expected.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox displays a decoded version of the URL in the URL bar so that it is easier to read for the user. It still sends the encoded string to the server.

Also, if you copy the contents of the URL bar and paste it into a text editor it will have the encoded characters in it.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. Do you have any reference links where I can know more about it?

Comment: @MoazzamKhan There's not much to know about it. Firefox behaves just like any other browser, only that it shows special characters in the URL bar.